# how to access a wsdl remotely

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

On the server, I run apache and I have a SOAP server. I have put the WSDL file on /var/www/html/custom.wsdl

I want to view this file in a browser, so I type http://myip.com/custom.wsdl in Chrome and the file gets downloaded and I type http://myip.com/custom.wsdl?wsdl and the same thing, the file gets downloaded.

What steps have I missed in allowing remote access to my wsdl file?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like things are working just fine. The file gets downloaded, which means:

1. The WSDL *is* available remotely and
2. Your server is sending the response with [the `Content-Disposition: attachment` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Responses)

Comment: but when I add ?wsdl to the end of any other soap servers, the wsdl file content is displayed. And in my case, it is not. The question is why is my file content not showing?